# How to color individual points on scatter plots based on their type using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on the Iris data and trying to use scatter plot, while I was able to get the output, I'd like to know how I can color the points based on their species, using matplotlib.

I've using the following syntax:

```
iris.plot.scatter(x='petal_length', y='petal_width') 
iris.plot(kind='scatter', x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width')
```

Also is there any way to use a single line of code to create two scatter plots for sepal_length/width and petal_length/width while coloring based on species?

Comment: I believe you should have a column named `type` or whatever. just add as a parameter `c='type'`.

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question. Having said that, IMCoins is probably right. But who knows.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the colors correct in a single call to the plotting function is a bit tedious.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u, inv = np.unique(iris.species.values, return_inverse=True)
ax = iris.plot.scatter(x='petal_length', y='petal_width', 
                  c=inv, cmap="brg", colorbar=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I would hence recommend to loop over the species, with the additional advantage of being able to easily put a legend into the plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for n, grp in iris.groupby("species"):
    plt.scatter(grp.petal_length, grp.petal_width, label=n)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

An easy solution is also to use seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, hue="species")
g.map(plt.scatter, 'petal_length','petal_width').add_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]